# Mysql - can I have a View that is an in memory image of a table

Tags: sql, mysql, database, view

I have a table with about 3000 records that I query often.
Does mysql provide some sort of View that can load the table in memory and stay synced with my table (similar to a cache), so i can query this view and have really fast results?

Comment: MySQL will likely already cache the data in memory, especially for such a small table. If things are too slow, you're better off tuning your queries, and making sure the proper indexes are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't think a view would help unless the underlying table were also in memory, which you can ensure by creating it thus...

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

13.9 of the reference manual has the details.